# How to prompt for input using an existing variable in the prompt

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to ask the user for a value of some variable, but at the same time, showing him the last value used (at the termination of the program, the values are saved to a file, and loaded at the start of the program).

Something like this:

***Enter new radius value (R=12.6) :***
*... user enters 12.7 ...*
***Enter new pi value (pi=3.14) :***
***Enter new height value (h=30.0) :***

Usually I would write the first one with *write* statement, then *read* the new one (in Fortran, for example). In MATLAB however, I don't know how to write something out with *input* statement. Are there some other statements for getting input ?

Comment: @MatlabDoug - MATLAB is okey, my mistake there, but fortran is no longer an acronym, but a name, and it is written in lowercase.

Comment: @Idigas  So it is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#cite_note-0  Guess that shows that when I last used Fortran it was FORTRAN 77! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the command `input` for this, combined with `sprintf`.

```
%# set defaults
radius = 12.6;

%# ask for inputs
tmp = input(sprintf('Enter new radius value (R=%4.2f)\n',radius));
%# if the user hits 'return' without writing anything, tmp is empty and the default is used
if ~isempty(tmp)
    radius = tmp;
end
```

As an alternative, you may want to look into [INPUTDLG](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/inputdlg.html)